# Can someone break this syntax down for me { [ nameValuePair1[, nameValuePair2[, ...nameValuePairN] ] ] }

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm looking through the MDN web docs and have seen this parameters for Object

```
// Object initialiser or literal
{ [ nameValuePair1[, nameValuePair2[, ...nameValuePairN] ] ] }
```

However, I'm struggling to understand what I'm actually looking at, I know it's an object literal, but the bracket notation is throwing me

Comment: It means that the argument is optional and can contain an array with one or more elements of nameValuePair

Comment: It doesn't mean object notation. It  means the parameter is optional.

Comment: Thanks, Understand this now.

Comment: Brackets `[]` mean the arguments are ***optional***. 
Comma `,` means they must be separated by commas.
`NameValuePair` of an object literal is standard notation for Object properties in JavaScript. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/d3krnyLf/)